# Are there two gamma vectors in multilevel models with more than one random effect?

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

For a multilevel model with random intercepts with $n$ subjects and $p$ fixed parameters the usual formula is

$$Y = X\beta + Z\gamma + \epsilon $$

with the following dimensions:

$Y - n\times 1 \\
X - n\times p\\
\beta-  p\times 1 \\
Z - n\times k \\
\gamma - k\times 1\\
\epsilon - n\times 1$

But what happens to the dimensions of $Z$ and $\gamma$ when there are two random effects (e.g. intercept and slope?) Or more than two?

Since $Y$ is always going to be $n\times 1$ the dimension of $Z\gamma$ must be $n\times 1$, so, are there then two (or more) $\gamma$ vectors?

Comment: You seem a little confused about the meaning of $k,$ because after introducing it, the rest of your post implicitly takes it always to be $1.$  Isn't your question answered merely by allowing $k$ to be greater than $1$??

Comment: Thanks.  I think I have figured this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just providing two fictional examples for illustration that helped me get a better grasp at the matrix notation. First, consider a model containing only a random intercept:

$$
y_{ij}= \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{ij} + u_{0j} +\varepsilon_{ij} = (\beta_0 + u_{0j}) + \beta_1 x_{ij} + \varepsilon_{ij}
$$

where $y_{ij}$ denotes the $i$-th observation of group $j$ of the response, and $x_{ij}$  and $\varepsilon_{ij}$ the respective predictor and error term.

The matrix notation for this model can be written as:

$$
\underset{{(N\times 1)}}{\mathbf{Y}}=  \underset{{(N\times p)}}{\mathbf{X}}\underset{{(p\times 1)}}{\beta} + \underset{{(N\times q)}}{\mathbf{Z}} \underset{{(q\times 1)}}{\mathbf{b}} + \underset{{(N\times 1)}}{\varepsilon}
$$

where $q$ denotes the number of random effects. Specifically, assume that we have $J = 2$ groups each with $n_1 = n_2 = 2$ observations, so $N=4$. We have $p = 2$ predictors including the intercept and $q = 2$ random effects (2 intercepts). The model is:

\begin{align*}
y_{ij} &=\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{ij} + u_{0j} + \varepsilon_{ij} \\
y_{11} &=\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{11} + u_{01} + \varepsilon_{11} \\
y_{21} &=\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{21} + u_{01} + \varepsilon_{21} \\
y_{12} &=\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{12} + u_{02} + \varepsilon_{11} \\
y_{22} &=\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{22} + u_{02} + \varepsilon_{22}
\end{align*}

or in matrix form:

$$
\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X}\beta + \mathbf{Z} \mathbf{b} + \varepsilon
$$

$$
\underset{{(4\times 1)}}{\begin{bmatrix}
y_{11} \\
y_{21} \\
y_{12} \\
y_{22}
\end{bmatrix}} = 
\underset{{(4\times 2)}}{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_{11} \\
1 & x_{21} \\
1 & x_{12} \\
1 & x_{22}
\end{bmatrix}}
\underset{{(2\times 1)}}{\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_{0} \\
\beta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}} +
\underset{{(4\times 2)}}{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}}
\underset{{(2\times 1)}}{\begin{bmatrix}
u_{01} \\
u_{02}
\end{bmatrix}} + 
\underset{{(4\times 1)}}{\begin{bmatrix}
\varepsilon_{11} \\
\varepsilon_{21} \\
\varepsilon_{12} \\
\varepsilon_{22}
\end{bmatrix}}
$$

---

The second example is like the first one but now we include random slopes:

$$
y_{ij}= \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{ij} + u_{0j} + u_{1j}x_{ij} + \varepsilon_{ij} = (\beta_0 + u_{0j}) + (\beta_{1} + u_{1j})x_{ij} + \varepsilon_{ij}
$$

where $y_{ij}$ denotes the $i$-th observation of group $j$ of the response, and $x_{ij}$  and $\varepsilon_{ij}$ the respective predictor and error term.

Again assuming $J = 2$ groups with $n_1 = n_2 = 2$ observations each, so that $N=4$. We have $p = 2$ predictors including the intercept. The model is:

\begin{align*}
y_{ij} &=\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{ij} + u_{0j} + u_{1j}x_{ij} + \varepsilon_{ij} \\
y_{11} &=\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{11} + u_{01} + u_{11}x_{11} + \varepsilon_{11} \\
y_{21} &=\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{21} + u_{01} + u_{11}x_{21} + \varepsilon_{21} \\
y_{12} &=\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{12} + u_{02} + u_{12}x_{12} + \varepsilon_{12} \\
y_{22} &=\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{22} + u_{02} + u_{12}x_{22} + \varepsilon_{22}
\end{align*}

Or in matrix form (we have $q = 4$ random effects: 2 intercepts and 2 slopes):

$$
\underset{{(4\times 1)}}{\begin{bmatrix}
y_{11} \\
y_{21} \\
y_{12} \\
y_{22}
\end{bmatrix}} = 
\underset{{(4\times 2)}}{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_{11} \\
1 & x_{21} \\
1 & x_{12} \\
1 & x_{22}
\end{bmatrix}}
\underset{{(2\times 1)}}{\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_{0} \\
\beta_{1}
\end{bmatrix}} +
\underset{{(4\times 4)}}{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_{11} & 0 & 0 \\
1 & x_{21} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & x_{12} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & x_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix}}
\underset{{(4\times 1)}}{\begin{bmatrix}
u_{01} \\
u_{11} \\
u_{02} \\
u_{22}
\end{bmatrix}}
\begin{matrix}
\text{Random intercept of group 1} \\
\text{Random slope of group 1} \\
\text{Random intercept of group 2} \\
\text{Random slope of group 2} 
\end{matrix} + 
\underset{{(4\times 1)}}{\begin{bmatrix}
\varepsilon_{11} \\
\varepsilon_{21} \\
\varepsilon_{12} \\
\varepsilon_{22}
\end{bmatrix}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @whuber's comment, I think I have figured this out. I'm not sure why I was blocking on this .... it's odd how sometimes a simple comment can clear things up.

The key is that k can be greater than 1 without affecting the dimensions of $z\gamma$ since k is the columns of Z and rows of $\gamma$.